# No Removable Devices in VMWare

Tags: vmware

I've installed VMWare on a new Ubuntu 11.10 PC and am unable to see any of my Removable Devices in the list.

Do I need to first enable these? If so, how?

Or... Is this a permissions thing where I need to add my user account to the VMWare group of something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that the host (Ubuntu) claims the device as soon as you plug it in - at least thats what happens for me (VMWare Workstation 8). If i eject the device from ubuntu it's automatically claimed by the guest OS if you have configured a USB device.

[image: VMWare Settings]

At least a Windows7 guest recognizes it perfectly.